# Refresh Auto Layout when view is removed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to use Auto Layout for a simple interface.

[image]

Sometimes, depending on the information received by the server we need to remove the `UIImageView` (when there is no image to display).

If I just do `[image removeFromSuperview]` then everything under the image  applies its constraints to the top of the super view instead of the "merchant description" label.

I've tried just updating the frame but apparently this is not allowed. I tried to PIN the merchant description and the VIP Discounts with a different priority label but apparently that option is gone in the new version of Xcode.

Comment: Instead of removing the view, make height constrain for it and set it to 0 when you dont want to see it . rest of the views should be relative to bottom of that image

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski When in the life cycle is it best to set the height constraint to 2?

Comment: There is updateConstrains method for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate and deactivate constraints in code. Create two constraints in IB, one for the layout with the image view present, and another without it. Create an `IBOutlet` connected to each constraint. Uncheck the "installed" box for whichever you consider to be not the default:

[image: IB constraint configuration]

When you remove the image view, change the constraints' active statuses appropriately:

```
[imageViewPresentConstraint setActive:NO];
[imageViewAbsentConstraint setActive:YES];
```

Do the reverse if the image view is ever restored to the view. **N.B.** be sure in all cases to deactivate before activating to avoid the classic log message about conflicts.